# Неправильный вывод даты на сайте

Tags: дата, база-данных, php, yii

Доброго времени суток всем!

Дело в следующем: когда на сайте я создаю новость, то в поле `post_date` БД также забивается дата в виде целого числа, т.е. количество секунд с помощью функции `time()`, но когда я забиваю новость, допустим, сегодня 14.11.2014, то на сайте отображается 15.02.2014.
На сайте не получается разместить новость моложе 30 августа (1417368900).
Помогите с этой неприятной ситуацией разобраться.

Вывод:

```
$

month = array(
     'Янв', 'Фев', 'Март', 'Апр', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Авг','Сен', 'Окт', 'Ноя', 'Дек'
);

 $day = date('d', $model->post_date);
 $m = date('N', $model->post_date);
$year = date('Y', $model->post_date);
?>
<div style="float: left;" class="date">
    <span class="day"><?php  echo($day); ?></span>
    <span class="month"><?php  echo($month[$m]); ?></span>
    <span class="year"><?php echo($year); ?></span>
</div>
<h1 style="margin-left: 100px;text-align: left;margin-bottom: 20px;"><?php echo $model->title; ?></h1>
<?php $m =0;?>

запись в бд
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new News;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['News']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['News'];
            $model->post_date = time();
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```

В базе поле `post_date ---> int(10)` хранит секунды.

Comment: Может, вы код покажите, непонятно, как вы так даты преобразуете, что они у вас не сходятся. На вашем месте в mysql  я бы использовал тип Datatime (или просто Data).

Comment: @Flur, может datetime, а не Datatime?

Comment: @MasterAlex виноват, но думаю, смысл понятен.

Answer (score 2):

Еще лучше сделайте поле:

```
timestamp default current_timestamp
```

И забудьте про ручное добавление даты.

Comment: Кстати да, помню, пытался добавить в  Yii, и не получилось, падало с ошибкой, сейчас погуглил - пишут, что нужно удалить у этого поля параметр required, чтобы заработало.

Comment: Я дополнил свой вопрос, посмотрите, пожалуйста, не знаю, в чем тут может быть подвох.

Comment: @telmed, не знаю. Сложно диагностировать. Скорее всего, не влазит, хотя вроде должно. Сделайте поле int unsigned.  
Хотя хранить в int - это вообще бред. Если Вам понадобится искать по датам, наткнетесь на костыли.    
Делайте или timestamp, или datetime.

Comment: @Ray, ну почему же бред? Имхо, очень удобно. Не зависишь от настроек timezone на стороне БД, меньше проблем с форматированием даты при выводе на страницу, да и поиск особых сложностей не вызывает.

Comment: @KiTE, если нужна независимость от тайм зон, то мускуль настраивается на гринвич. Если нужна будет работа с зонами, то пожалуйста.
Также костыльный нечеловекочитаемый поис по UNIX_TIMESTAMP.  
Поиск по timestamp рабофтает быстрее, чем по int. Проверял лично: hashcode.ru/questions/361368/table-группировка-по-дате-в-mysql. 
В общем аргументов в пользу int гораздо меньше.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы, надо подумать.

Comment: @Ray, поиск в первую очередь зависит от индексов, а не от типов данных. Настройка MySQL на GMT не сильно поможет, даже наоборот, может ввести в заблуждение. Например, если вы из php запишите в БД значение от `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`, то это значение будет с учетом таймзоны из настроек php, но в MySQL оно запишется как GMT, а это неправильно.

Но мои аргументы скорее в пользу удобств в разработке. В php с чистым `int` работать удобнее. Не нужно делать двойное преобразование. Тем более если используются фреймворки yii, symfony, laravel, etc. со своими orm-ами.

Answer (score 1):

Ну 2014 уже, ну право дело

```
date(DATE_ISO8601)
```

еще лучше, еще поддерживаемей, еще более рожее овощее гибчайше

```
$this->_date = new DateTime;
public function getDate()
{
    return $this->_date->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php **PHP 5 >= 5.2.0**

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сохранять дату таким способом:

```
$this->date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

где $this - название модели.

В базе тип поля сделать `datetime` (как написано выше в комментариях), мне это помогло, когда нужно было сохранять текущую дату поста в базе.

Comment: Я дополнил свой вопрос, посмотрите, пожалуйста, не знаю, в чем тут может быть подвох.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ.